# Big picture or guide on programming related topics?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, coding-style, code-reuse

I was wondering if someone could give a big picture of how the following topics and others not mentioned are related:

- "code reuse"
- "refactor"
- "design pattern"
- "coding/programming standard/style"
- ...

I have heard of these from people's talk and books' names, but got overwhelmed by these names. May I get some organization and big picture from here?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to buy a copy of Dave Thomas and Andy Hunt's "The Pragmatic Programmer". There are plenty of other good books that also try to tie things together, but that's an excellent place to start.

Comment: [Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer) is worth every penny.

Answer (score 3):

- "coding standard" is what the source file looks like, how many spaces or tabs to use.  Uppercase/lowercase and so on.
- "design pattern" is the structure of the code, the data structures and algorithms.
- "refactor" is the process of changing the structure of the code while preserving its behavior.  Usually the motivation for refactoring is to structure the code into well known "design patterns".
- "code reuse" is typically the bonus you get from successful refactoring.  That is when your source file has code related to a cohesive set of features.  You have eliminated other concerns from the code so that you no longer worry about the extra baggage you bring along should you try to use the code somewhere else.